# conditionally modify text from json inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller which get a json from a service, and put into divs with a ng-repeat. But I need to alter my text if there is more than 20 char and keep the original when the user click on the div to display the whole text.

How can I do that ? I'm completely stuck...

Thanx.

Comment: You would have better luck in getting an answer if you post some code and show what you tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you share some code that would be better but I think what you need is a filter.
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Define something like this in your js :

```
filter('limitedLength', function() {
    return function(input) {
        if (input.length > 20) {
            input = input.substring(0, 19);
        }

        return input;

    }
```

and then in your html :

```
{{yourText | limitedLength}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the limitTo filter either in your controller or template. 
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:limitTo

A simple plunk to improvise based on your needs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/crBn3lZfMta1TOMv6NWS?p=preview

Comment: thanx. Both anwsers helped me.

Comment: Glad it helped, @peaceLion Would you be kind to help with credit!